# std::unordered map with custom key fails at ~ 31,000 elements

Tags: c++, stl

I am storing pointers to a component class in an unordered map using a custom key.

( For the motivation for doing so, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56688344/16582 )

I can store up to 30,000 components without problems.  The container fails completely and silently when I store 31,000 components.

( I first thought of the maximum value of a signed 16 bit integer, but that is slightly larger at 32767 )

I suspect there is something wrong with the hashing of the custom key, because using a standard key does not show this problem.  For this feasibility test I do not care about performance, so I am using a very simple and easy to understand hash function.  I have tried a couple of different hashing functions, but all show the same problem - the code below has the simplest.

The minimal complete program code below behaves as expected for 30,000 components

```
Map contains 30000
type 12 found type 12 found total 10, OK
```

but fails for 31,000 components

```
Map contains 31000
type 12 found type 12 found total 0, ERROR! Incorrect component count recovered
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <unordered_map>

#define maxScene 10
#define maxLayer 10
#define maxType 100
#define maxID   10000

#define COUNT_COMPS_FOR_EACH_SCENE_LAYER_TYPE 10

// OK for 30, but fails for 31
#define COUNT_TYPES 31

using namespace std;

class Component
{
public:
    int myID;
    static long long lastID;
    Component()
    {
        myID = ++lastID;
    }
};

long long Component::lastID = -1;

class cKey
{
public:
    size_t scene;
    size_t layer;
    size_t type;
    long long id;

    void Display() const;

};

struct KeyHash
{
public:
    size_t operator()(const cKey & key) const
    {
        std::hash<string> shash;
        stringstream ss;
        ss << setw(3) << key.scene << setw(3)<< key.layer << setw(4) << key.type;
        //key.Display();
        //cout << " " << ss.str() << "\n";
        return shash( ss.str() );
    }
};
struct KeyEqual
{
public:
    bool operator()(const cKey & key1, const cKey & key2) const
    {
        if( key1.scene != key2.scene )
            return false;
        if( key1.layer != key2.layer )
            return false;
        if( key1.type != key2.type )
            return false;
        if( key1.id != key2.id )
            return false;
        return true;
    }
};

void cKey::Display() const
{
    cout << scene <<" "<< layer <<" "<< type <<" "<<id ;
}

int main()
{

    unordered_map< cKey, Component*,
                   KeyHash, KeyEqual  > theMap;

    // store components
    int insertCount = 0;
    cKey key;
    for( key.scene = 0; key.scene < maxScene; key.scene++ )
    {
        for( key.layer = 0; key.layer < maxLayer; key.layer++ )
        {
            // store specified number of types
            for( key.type = 0; key.type < COUNT_TYPES; key.type++ )
            {
                // store specified number of components for this scene, layer and type
                for( int k = 0; k < COUNT_COMPS_FOR_EACH_SCENE_LAYER_TYPE; k++ )
                {
                    insertCount++;
                    Component* pc = new Component;
                    key.id = pc->myID;

                    auto ret = theMap.insert( make_pair( key, pc ));
                    if( ! ret.second )
                    {
                        cout << "insert failed ";
                        key.Display();
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Map contains " << theMap.size() << "\n";

    // iterate over components of one type in a particular scene and layer
    key.scene = 3;
    key.layer = 2;
    key.type  = 12;
    cout << "type " << key.type << " found ";
    int count = 0;
    for( key.id = 0; key.id < maxID; key.id++ )
    {
        auto it = theMap.find( key );
        if( it == theMap.end() )
            continue;
        count++;
    }
    cout << "type " << key.type << " found total "<< count << ", ";
    if( count != COUNT_COMPS_FOR_EACH_SCENE_LAYER_TYPE )
        cout << "ERROR! Incorrect component count recovered\n";
    else
        cout << "OK";

    return 0;
}
```

Fixed production code at https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/d71b158b32e4dd8ffaf8cbe93cf3f180 if anyone wants to suggest a faster hash ...

Comment: Wow, using a `std::stringstream` to create a hash! It's hard to be more inefficient. Also take a look at `std::tie`.

Comment: Why is id considered as part of the equality but not as part of the hash?

Comment: @Deduplicator Please read my description of the hash function

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts  I tried using the id as part of the hash - same problem.  This is simpler, as I try to track down the 31,000 element problem.  People! this is test code, not production.

Comment: @ravenspoint sorry for my previous comment. I didn't meant to bother you, but I was trying to understand what you were doing. If I use in the for loop where you count key.id <= Component::lastID instead of key.id < maxID the test passes.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts Well spotted!  That is the problem. ( post answer and I'll accept )

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts production code at https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/d71b158b32e4dd8ffaf8cbe93cf3f180

Comment: @ravenspoint thanks! Sorry if I am a pain, but shouldn't key.id <= Component::lastID . I mean lastID is the last ID already assigned.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts No pain - well spotted again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write the following as loop that counts the elements

```
for (key.id = 0; key.id <= Component::lastID; key.id++)
{
    auto it = theMap.find(key);
    if (it == theMap.end())
        continue;
    count++;
}
```

the test passes. I think that it is simply a problem of keeping track of the greatest possible id.